# Measure theory question about Integral.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f \ge 0$ be a measurable function on measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$.  Let $\mu$ be a measure.  How to prove that if
$$
\int f \mathrm{d}\mu = 0,
$$
then we have $f = 0$ almost everywhere?

This is an exercise 1.4.1 of Probability: Theory and Examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** let $A_n:=\{x\mid f(x)\geq n^{—1}\}$. What is $\mu(A_n)$? And $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n$? Its measure?

Answer (score 1):

By Markov's inequality

$$\mu\left( \{x : f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\} \right) \leq n \int f d\mu = 0.$$